# Keras: inconsistent results when fitting ConvNets in two different ways

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, image-recognition

I'm trying to use VGG16 network to do image classification. I've tried two different ways to do it which should be approximately equivalent as far as I understand, yet the results are very different.

**Method 1:** Extract features using VGG16 and fit these features using a custom fully connected network. Here is the code:

```python
model = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                    input_shape=(imsize,imsize,3),
                    pooling='avg')
model_pred = keras.Sequential()
model_pred.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, input_dim=512, activation='sigmoid'))
model_pred.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model_pred.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'))
model_pred.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model_pred.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_categories, activation='sigmoid'))
model_pred.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                   optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), metrics=['accuracy'])

(xtr, ytr) = tools.extract_features(model, 3000, imsize, datagen,
                                    rootdir + '/train',
                                    pickle_name = rootdir + '/testpredstrain.pickle')
(xv, yv) = tools.extract_features(model, 300, imsize, datagen,
                                  rootdir + '/valid1',
                                  pickle_name = rootdir + '/testpredsvalid.pickle')

model_pred.fit(xtr, ytr, epochs = 10, validation_data = (xv, yv), verbose=1)
```

(The function `extract_features()` simply uses Keras `ImageDataGenerator` to generate sample images and returns the output after using `model.predict()` on those images)

**Method 2:** Take the VGG16 network without the top part, set all the convolutional layers to non-trainable and add a few densely connected layers that are trainable. Then fit using keras `fit_generator()`. Here is the code:

```python
model2 = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                    input_shape=(imsize,imsize,3),
                    pooling='avg')
for ll in model2.layers:
    ll.trainable = False

out1 = keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='softmax')(model2.layers[-1].output)
out1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(out1)
out1 = keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='softmax')(out1)
out1 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(out1)
out1 = keras.layers.Dense(num_categories, activation='softmax')(out1)
model2 = keras.Model(inputs = model2.input, outputs = out1)
model2.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
               optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
               metrics=['accuracy'])


model2.fit_generator(train_gen,
                     steps_per_epoch = 100,
                     epochs = 10,
                     validation_data = valid_gen,
                     validation_steps = 10)
```

The number of epochs, samples, etc. are not exactly the same in both methods, but they don't need to be to notice the inconsistency: method 1 yields validation accuracy of 0.47 after just one epoch and gets as high as 0.7-0.8 and even better when I'm using larger number of samples to fit. Method 2, however, gets stuck at validation accuracy of 0.1-0.15 and never gets any better no matter how much I train.

Also, method 2 is considerably slower than method 1 even though it seems to me that they should be approximately as fast (when taking into account the time it takes to extract the features in method 1).

Comment: why are you using sigmoid as activation function in the first method and softmax in the second?

Comment: Oh boy that is a stupid mistake. I copied the second part of the code from some other tests of mine and did not see there was difference. With the same activation functions, I actually now get similar accuracies for both methods. Now there is only the problem of speed; why is it that method 2 is so much slower than method 1? They have the same number of trainable parameters after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your first method you extract features with vgg16 pre-trained model **once** and then you train - finetune your network while in your second approach you are constantly passing your images through every layer including vgg's layers **at every epoch**. That causes your model to run slower with your second method.

Comment: Yes, but the total number of images passed through the network is similar in both cases. In the first method, I extract features from 3000 images (=3000 forward passes) and train for 10 epochs with 3000 steps each. In the second method I have 10 epochs with 100 steps per epoch (=1000 (?) forward passes). This is actually less images than in the first method. Correct me if I'm wrong, but as long as I don't reuse the same images too many times, the two methods should have similar speeds.

Comment: In the second method you have 10 epochs with 100 steps per epoch plus batch size. What is your batch size?

Comment: Oh that is a good point. My batch size is 32, which means (I guess) that I am actually generating 32000 images. Sorry about the stupidity, I'm fairly new to all this neural network stuff and apparently make a lot of basic mistakes :).

Comment: Don' t worry. We all make mistakes.